# Kubernetes Cluster - Acces httpd from external Connection refused

Tags: kubernetes

This is my deployment:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: httpd-service-cloudops
  namespace: httpd-namespace-cloudops
  labels:
    app: apache_app
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: apache_app
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 30004
  externalIPs:
    - 192.168.101.72
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: httpd-deployment-cloudops
  namespace: httpd-namespace-cloudops
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: apache_app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: apache_app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: httpd-container-cloudops
          image: httpd:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
```

And the output if I try to access trough curl i get Connection refused error:

curl 192.168.101.72

curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.101.72 port 80: Connection refused

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The port that is open from outside is 30004 (the nodeport).

```
curl http://192.168.101.72:30004
```

should work.

Comment: I already tried, forgot to mention it.
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.101.72 port 30004: Connection refused